Cannot send verification email link for AWS cognito
I am using AWS cognito in my ionic app to create a user but the default setting is to send a verification code, and it's working, but when i try to change the setting in the cognito console to send a verification link instead of code I get error 400 in the console, and the user is not created. Keep in mind that I am not changing anything in my code, I am just changing the settings in the console
